# Images do not align and are different heights

Tags: css, image, alignment, height, overflow

I have a problem with images displaying in different heights and text underneath not aligning. 
this is the mark up, I have a six row containers to display 6 images

```
           <div class="row">
                <div class="posts">
                    <img src="images/bond.jpg" alt="quantum of solace">
                    <h3 class="title">Quantum of Solace</h3>
                    <p class="post-info">PG13 | 106min</p>
                </div>
            </div>
```

I am setting each post to 14% coz there are 6 of them allowing for 2.5% margin right. I tried to wrap image in a div and set that to overflow hidden, but didn't work.

```
.row {
    width: 100%;
}

.posts {
    width: 14%;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 2.5%;
}
.posts img {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    border-radius: 0.5em;
}
```

Comment: Seems to work fine in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ecmy1z7p/). Can you post a snippet that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: yeah but images you have used are all the same proportions, my ones are not

Comment: Ehm... so your complaint is that images which have different heights, are displayed with different heights? That wasn't very clear. Then what do you want? Do you want some of the images to be stretched vertically to fit the heights of others?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can change the disposition of the nodes, you could align the text below the images using: **display:table**. See the next example:

```css
.table {
    display: table ;
}

.row {
    display: table-row ;
}

.header, .title, .post-info {
    display: table-cell ;
    width: 14%;
    padding: 0 1.25% 0.25% 1.25% ;
    vertical-align: top ;
}

.header img {
    max-width: 100%;
    border-radius: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="header">
            <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/2/2d/Quantum_of_Solace_-_UK_cinema_poster.jpg" alt="quantum of solace">
        </div>
        <div class="header">
            <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/6/66/E_t_the_extra_terrestrial_ver3.jpg" alt="E.T. the Extra-Terrestrial ">
        </div>
        <div class="header">
            <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/a/a2/Star_Wars_The_Force_Awakens_Theatrical_Poster.jpg" alt="Star Wars VII">
        </div>
        <div class="header">
            <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/8/8e/DisneyCheshireCat.jpg" alt="Alice in Wonderland">
        </div>
        <div class="header">
            <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/6/6c/XFilesMoviePoster.jpg" alt="The X-Files">
        </div>
        <div class="header">
            <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/27/Poster_-_Gone_With_the_Wind_01.jpg/440px-Poster_-_Gone_With_the_Wind_01.jpg" alt="Gone with the Wind">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <h4 class="title">Quantum of Solace</h4>
        <h4 class="title">E.T. the Extra-Terrestrial </h4>
        <h4 class="title">Star Wars: Episode VII The Force Awakens</h4>
        <h4 class="title">Alice in Wonderland</h4>
        <h4 class="title">The X-Files: Fight the Future</h4>
        <h4 class="title">Gone with the Wind</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <p class="post-info">PG13 | 106min</p>
        <p class="post-info">G | 115min</p>
        <p class="post-info">PG13 | 136min</p>
        <p class="post-info">G | 187min</p>
        <p class="post-info">PG13 | 121min</p>
        <p class="post-info">G | 238min</p>
    </div>
</div>
```